# How to return different types of model from a WebAPI controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller like this

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<InboxPatientModel>))]
    [Route("~/api/Messages/search")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSearch(string serchTerm = "", string messageFor = "p")
    {
        try
        {
            if(messageFor == "p")
            {
                var inboxMessages = MessageToPatientList.Get(serchTerm);
                return Ok(inboxMessages);
            }
            else
            {
                var outboxMessages = MessageToDoctorList.Get(serchTerm);
                return Ok(outboxMessages);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //some code for exception handling....
        }
    }
```

Here `MessageToPatientList.Get` and `MessageToDoctorList.Get` return list of different types say `InboxPatientModel` and `InboxDoctorModel`.

Is it possible to decorate the action with `[ResponseType(...)]` so that it can be dynamic and different types of list can be returned?

Comment: The ResponseType is only used for documentation purposes by the ApiExplorer when an automatic API description is requested. It has no effect on the processing of requests. That being said you can use multiple ResponseType attributes, i.e. `[ResponseType(typeof(List<InboxPatientModel>)), ResponseType(typeof(List<InboxDoctorModel>))]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could merge the different types of lists;

```
public class PatientModel
{
    public List<InboxPatientModel> Patients { get; set; }

    public List<InboxDoctorModel> Doctors { get; set; }
}

[ResponseType(typeof(PatientModel))]
[Route("~/api/Messages/search")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSearch(string serchTerm = "", string messageFor = "p")
{
    try
    {
        var patientModel = new PatientModel();
        if (messageFor == "p")
        {
            var inboxMessages = MessageToPatientList.Get(serchTerm);
            patientModel.Patients = inboxMessages;
        }
        else
        {
            var outboxMessages = MessageToDoctorList.Get(serchTerm);
            patientModel.Doctors = inboxMessages;
        }
        return Ok(patientModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //some code for exception handling....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The URL is already different when searching for doctors and patients, so there is no benefit in having a single action.

Just write two Actions "GetDoctors" and "GetPatients" which return the types you want.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<InboxPatientModel>))]
[Route("~/api/Messages/searchpatients")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPatients(string searchTerm = "")
{
}

[ResponseType(typeof(List<InboxDoctorModel>))]
[Route("~/api/Messages/searchdoctors")]
public IHttpActionResult GetDoctors(string searchTerm = "")
{
}
```

Comment: Actually `InboxPatientModel` to show the inbox items and `InboxDoctorModel` to show sent/draft items in patient's mailbox. That is the reason for keeping the single action.

Comment: But its a different URL for those things anyway - messageFor is different.

Comment: I am actually aware of this approach but I wanted to stick with single method for simplicity to the client.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will run just fine. The `[ResponseType]` attribute is only used to give hints for the Web API documentation page and tools like Swagger.

While the attribute has `AllowMultiple=true` in its `AttributeUsage` attribute, I don't think those documentation tools support this.

And they shouldn't. Returning different types from an API depending on the size of the moon, the day of the week or the value of some parameters is a hell to implement, a hell to document and a hell to consume.

Instead consider reviewing the design. Why should the actual *type* of a message change depending on who is the recipient? What *is* different between the two types of messages?

On the contrary, find properties they *share*. Then extract a base class, say, `Message`, and decorate the method with an attribute `[ResponseType(typeof(Message))]`.

Answer (score 2):

Each resource (patient and doctor) should have its own controller action. I would do this:

1) Create two different controller actions: one for InboxPatientModel and another one for InboxDoctorModel.

2) At the client-side you determine, based on "messageFor", which controller action you need to call.

3) Eeach controller action would have a different ResponseType.